# Access vba filter button

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I am trying to make a form with two filter buttons. 
First button will + 1 to the filter and
second button will -1 to the filter.

so far I have.

```
 Dim ADD As String
 If Me.TypeID Is Empty Then
     'empty TypeID, do nothing
 Else
     ADD = Me.TypeID + 1
     DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[TypeID] = " & ADD
 End If
```

I am getting

> error 2427

because I can't trap if the next TypeID doesn't exist.

For example, I have now 4 records as TypeId. If I add 1, I will have 5 which I don't have.

Thank you.

Comment: Try with: `If IsNull(Me.TypeID) Then`

Comment: Is not working. I test it.

Comment: Also tried  `If IsEmpty(Me.TypeID) then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it.

```
 Dim Add As String
 Dim LastID As Integer

 LastID = DMax("TypeID", "tblType")

 If Me.TypeID = LastID Then
      'Empty TypeID, Do Nothing...
 Else
      Add = Me.TypeID + 1
      DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[TypeID] = " & Add
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to set:

```
Me.filter on = true
```

Comment: That's not necessary after `DoCmd.ApplyFilter`.